Package luacolor disables chickenize
I really would like to get my readers attention by printing one word in rainbow colors. Usually that works using the chickenize package. MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chickenize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\rainbowcolor

\blindtext

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:

Result:

But if I add \usepackage{luacolor}, the print is only in black. Adding the luacolor package disables chickenize.
I'm working on a larger document and even if I don't have luacolor, I don't get rainbowcolors working. Searching for an MWE I found that luacolor is one of the culprits, but there probably are more.
Question 1: What disables chickenize?
And I noticed that sometimes "LuaTeX-1.18.0" is producer of the document, in other cases it is "luahbtex-1.18.0". But I fail to find the switch, which command leads to which engine.
Q 2: If you could point out some documents where the mechanisms are described, how to get which producer.

Question 1
luacolor sets an attribute named LuaCol@Attribute to all nodes, and based on the value of that attribute it will inject pdf data at shipout time to make sure that the node is colored correctly.
In your example, all the glyph nodes LuaCol@Attribute's value is one, hence luacolor color them in black at shipout time, the corresponding color in this case.
Since chickenize adds the color data just after TeX breaks the paragraph into lines (at the post_linebreak_filter callback), and it happens before shipout, luacolor wins.
You can solve it by either by unsetting  LuaCol@Attribute (you should probably do that loacly):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{chickenize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{{\rainbowcolor\unsetattribute\LuaCol@Attribute #1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foo\blindtext
\end{document}


or better yet, use a code that is compatible with luacolor:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\directlua{

luatexbase.new_attribute"rainbow"
local setattribute = tex.setattribute
local traverse_id = node.traverse_id
local has_attribute = node.has_attribute
local set_attribute = node.set_attribute
local scan_keyword = token.scan_keyword
local scan_real = token.scan_real
local rainbow_step = 0.005
local rainbow_Rgb = 0.995 
local rainbow_rGb = 0.005   
local rainbow_rgB = 0.005
local rainind = 1          

local function rainbow_color()
    if rainind == 1 then
      rainbow_rGb = rainbow_rGb + rainbow_step
      if rainbow_rGb >= 1-rainbow_step then rainind = 2 end
    elseif rainind == 2 then
      rainbow_Rgb = rainbow_Rgb - rainbow_step
      if rainbow_Rgb <= rainbow_step then rainind = 3 end
    elseif rainind == 3 then
      rainbow_rgB = rainbow_rgB + rainbow_step
      rainbow_rGb = rainbow_rGb - rainbow_step
      if rainbow_rGb <= rainbow_step then rainind = 4 end
    elseif rainind == 4 then
      rainbow_Rgb = rainbow_Rgb + rainbow_step
      if rainbow_Rgb >= 1-rainbow_step then rainind = 5 end
    else 
      rainbow_rgB = rainbow_rgB - rainbow_step
      if rainbow_rgB <= rainbow_step then rainind = 1 end
    end
    return rainbow_Rgb.." "..rainbow_rGb.." "..rainbow_rgB.." rg"
           .." "..rainbow_Rgb.." "..rainbow_rGb.." "..rainbow_rgB.." RG"
end

local function add_rainbow_color(head)
    for n in traverse_id(node.id"glyph",head) do
        if has_attribute(n,luatexbase.attributes.rainbow) then
            set_attribute(n,luatexbase.attributes["LuaCol@Attribute"],oberdiek.luacolor.getvalue(rainbow_color()))
        end
    end
    return head
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_linebreak_filter',add_rainbow_color,'add rainbow')

local rainbowcolor = luatexbase.new_luafunction"rainbowcolor"
lua.get_functions_table()[rainbowcolor] = function() setattribute(luatexbase.attributes["rainbow"],1) end
token.set_lua("rainbowcolor", rainbowcolor, "protected")

local unrainbowcolor = luatexbase.new_luafunction"unrainbowcolor"
lua.get_functions_table()[unrainbowcolor] = function() setattribute(luatexbase.attributes["rainbow"], -0x7FFFFFFF) end
token.set_lua("unrainbowcolor", unrainbowcolor, "protected")

local rainbowstep = luatexbase.new_luafunction"rainbowstep"
lua.get_functions_table()[rainbowstep] = function() scan_keyword'=' rainbow_step = scan_real() end
token.set_lua("rainbowstep", rainbowstep, "protected")

}
\rainbowstep=0.1
\begin{document}
{\rainbowcolor foo bar baz} 
\blindtext

\rainbowcolor 
\blindtext

 \unrainbowcolor
\blindtext

\rainbowstep0.005
\rainbowcolor 
\blindtext
\end{document}


Notes

Unlike chickenize's \rainbowcolor, this one respect grouping and can be applied to a part of a paragraph, rather than only whole paragraphs, I find it more convenient, but if you prefer the code can be easily modified to work the same as chickenize.

You can change the value of rainbow_step with the \rainbowstep macro, the change is global and only the value at line breaking time is considered (like \baselineskip).

The code should be compatible with chickenize, unless I unknowingly overwritten some function or macro (apart from \(un)rainbowcolor)


Question 2
Not sure what you mean by "producer" (the PDF field? the first line in the log?), but the command lualatex use luahbtex by default. I think you should ask that in a different post, the two questions are really unrelated.

Thank you! I wasn't sure whether the different engines, lualatex and luahbtex and it changed in the PDF field. I tried to find out how to produce a lualatex-non-harfbuzz PDF, but failed to find any documentation. I'll follow your advice and ask another question.

The short solution works as expected. The directlua code crashes if I set rainbow_step = 0.1 and besides that colors the headline of the previous page :-)

@KeksDose As for the first problem, by changing rainbow_step at its initialization you also changed rainbow_Rgb etc., you will need to keep them as they are, so either change rainbow_step after defining rainbow_Rgb or define rainbow_Rgb independently. I edited the code by the latter suggestion. so you will be able to change the default value of rainbow_step. I also added a command \rainbowstep to help you change rainbow_step in the middle of the document (see the last note).

@KeksDose As for the second problem, I cannot reproduce, or I don't understand the problem, can you elaborate?

Not this morning, unfortunately I'm at work...
